# Trying to run "service nginx restart" from a non root user

Tags: services, polkit, authorization

I'm pretty new to the deployment world but this is what's going on. I have a new Ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS) droplet from DigitalOcean. I installed and configured nginx and everything is working smooth. I turn it on and off with: `service nginx start`/`service nginx stop` but I need to be able to do this with a different user called `pepito`.

When I try to run `service nginx start` with `pepito` I get:

```
~# service nginx restart
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to restart 'nginx.service'.
Authenticating as: pepito
Password:
```

But I'm going to be running this from Capistrano so I don't want to be asked to enter the password, so I added this to `visudo` like this:

```
pepito ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service nginx*
```

Tried again and same problem. Keep googling and reading and find out that `==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===` is a message from `Polkit` so I read a little about it and created the following file in: `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/nginx.pkla`

```
Identity=unix-user:pepito
Action=org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

Of course it doesn't work when I try to start and stop nginx from `pepito`. I don't know what else to try!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `visudo` command you edited the file `/etc/sudoers`, which only applies if you prefix your commands with `sudo`, in your case `sudo service nginx start`.

Comment: Thanks dude! It was driving me crazy. I'll just avoid using Polkit that I can't understand!

Comment: Sudo is the general mechanism in Linux/Unix to provide fine-grained access to superuser rights.